# Astro project has updated and cannot run local host with unknown terminal error Cannot find module 'astro/config' imported from ' astro.config.mjs

Tags: terminal, node-modules, vite, astrojs

I'm really sorry for my poorly written question, but very grateful for any help here as my business product for web dev has been breaking only in some projects, which makes me even more curious.

I was working on a project the day before, pushing git commits that would spin up in Netlify okay.
The very next day I come to my project not loading at all in local host with the following terminal error. I believe it has something to do with dependancies that were included with the 'Astro Stone' starter template I used at the beginning, or something inside of the astro.config.mjs file not being found in a new version requested???

Here is the terminal error followed by the Astro config.

Github repo: https://github.com/aidenwood/LTEK-v8.5

TERMINAL:

```
aiden@192-168-1-102 site % npm run dev

> astro-theme-stone@1.0.0 dev
> astro dev

10:42:14 AM [vite] Error when evaluating SSR module /Users/aiden/Documents/GitHub/LTEK : iSupport/LTEK-v8.5/site/astro.config.mjs: failed to import "astro/config"
|- Error: Cannot find module 'astro/config' imported from '/Users/aiden/Documents/GitHub/LTEK : iSupport/LTEK-v8.5/site/astro.config.mjs'
    at nodeImport (file:///usr/local/lib/node_modules/astro/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-2b82a1ce.js:56075:25)
    at ssrImport (file:///usr/local/lib/node_modules/astro/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-2b82a1ce.js:55977:30)
    at eval (eval at instantiateModule (file:///usr/local/lib/node_modules/astro/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-2b82a1ce.js:56036:28), <anonymous>:3:50)
    at instantiateModule (file:///usr/local/lib/node_modules/astro/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-2b82a1ce.js:56039:15)

Failed to load url astro/config (resolved id: astro/config) in /Users/aiden/Documents/GitHub/LTEK : iSupport/LTEK-v8.5/site/astro.config.mjs. Does the file exist?
Failed to load url astro-compress (resolved id: astro-compress) in /Users/aiden/Documents/GitHub/LTEK : iSupport/LTEK-v8.5/site/astro.config.mjs. Does the file exist?
[astro] Unable to load your Astro config

 error   Cannot find module 'astro/config' imported from '/Users/aiden/Documents/GitHub/LTEK : iSupport/LTEK-v8.5/site/astro.config.mjs'
  File:
    /usr/local/lib/node_modules/astro/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-2b82a1ce.js:56075:25
  Code:
    56074 |         if (!resolved) {
    > 56075 |             const err = new Error(`Cannot find module '${id}' imported from '${importer}'`);
            |                         ^
      56076 |             err.code = 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND';
      56077 |             throw err;
      56078 |         }
  Stacktrace:
Error: Cannot find module 'astro/config' imported from '/Users/aiden/Documents/GitHub/LTEK : iSupport/LTEK-v8.5/site/astro.config.mjs'
    at nodeImport (file:///usr/local/lib/node_modules/astro/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-2b82a1ce.js:56075:25)
    at ssrImport (file:///usr/local/lib/node_modules/astro/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-2b82a1ce.js:55977:30)
    at eval (eval at instantiateModule (file:///usr/local/lib/node_modules/astro/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-2b82a1ce.js:56036:28), <anonymous>:3:50)
    at instantiateModule (file:///usr/local/lib/node_modules/astro/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-2b82a1ce.js:56039:15)
```

ASTRO CONFIG

```
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';
import tailwind from '@astrojs/tailwind';
import compress from 'astro-compress';

// https://astro.build/config
export default defineConfig({
  experimental: {
    viewTransitions: true,
  },
  integrations: [tailwind(), compress()],
});
```

Thank you again for your time and any help if possible.

Local host to run an astro project. The project code should compile, and unfortunately this happened with another client a few months earlier. Really need help here.

Comment: What version of Astro are you using? Try reinstalling your project.

Comment: Astro 2.10.13

By reinstall, do you mean run npm install? Or is there something better to run? Tried that and still coming up with the same error.

Comment: Yep that's what I meant, install with your package manager. Depending on the size of the project, it may be easier to start over with a new working Astro project and migrate everything over. Issues like this can be surprisingly difficult to nail down.

Comment: Cheers, really appreciate the help Alex. Had to do that a few days ago to keep the workflow going. Really hoping to understand this issue for next time however. Has me stressing.